# Why doesn't simulating keystrokes with ControlSend work?

Tags: keypress, autoit

Simulating keystrokes with [`ControlSend()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlSend.htm) doesn't work:

```
While 1
   ControlSend("PokeMMO", "", "", "{DOWN}")
   Sleep(900)
   ControlSend("PokeMMO", "", "", "{DOWN}")
   Sleep(900)
   ControlSend("PokeMMO", "", "", "{DOWN}")
   Sleep(900)
   ControlSend("PokeMMO", "", "", "a")
   Sleep(Random(750, 2000, 1))
   ControlSend("PokeMMO", "", "", "a")
   Sleep(Random(750, 2000, 1))
   ControlSend("PokeMMO", "", "", "a")
   Sleep(Random(750, 2000, 1))
   ControlSend("PokeMMO", "", "", "a")
   Sleep(3000)
WEnd
```

[Au3Info](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/au3spy.htm):

> Title: РokеММO,
> Class: LWJGL

```
Global $sProcess = "javaw.exe" ;PokeMMO Process

ControlSend(_Process2Win($sProcess), "", "", "{DOWN}")

Func _Process2Win($pid)
    If IsString($pid) Then $pid = ProcessExists($pid)
    If $pid = 0 Then Return -1
    $list = WinList()
    For $i = 1 To $list[0][0]
        If $list[$i][0] <> "" And BitAND(WinGetState($list[$i][1]), 2) Then
            $wpid = WinGetProcess($list[$i][0])
            If $wpid = $pid Then Return $list[$i][0]
        EndIf
    Next
    Return -1
EndFunc   ;==>_Process2Win
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use WinGetHandle first to recieve a handle to the Window and then use this handle in the ControlSend function, which should work. It looks like the following:

```
$handle = WinGetHandle("[TITLE:PokeMMO; CLASS:LWJGL]")
ControlSend($handle, Default, $handle, "{Down}")
```

Try to display the content of handle first to confirm, you're recieving a working handle. Like `ConsoleWrite($handle)` or `MsgBox(1, "Handle", WinGetTitle($handle))`

Go, give it a try ;-)
And good luck!

Comment: It doesnt work. I also tried something else by my self. I updated it!

Comment: What's the content of $handle then? Can you receive a proper title?